# Testing a controller with duplicate name using WebMvcTest

Tags: java, spring, testing

I have 2 controllers wih the same name, in two different packages :

```
package1.MyController
package2.MyController
```

I want to test the controller in package1, using WebMvcTest.
So I specify the name and package of the controller in the @WebMvcTest annotation, like this :

`@WebMvcTest(value = package1.MyController.class)`
(I assume Spring will know which controller i want to test)

But I get the following error :
`Caused by: org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'MyController' for bean class [package1.MyController] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [package2.MyController]`

Can someone explain that to me? 
And is there a way to tell Spring which controller class I want to test (except giving them different names, of course)? Adding a different bean name on each controller seams useless because the parameter on WebMvcTest only accepts class names.

Comment: Please provide information such as the code. It is much easier for the members here to help you with that.

Comment: Declaring a name would help, however why is that test even loading the other classes. Can you add your test class? Also this will be an issue in your actual application as well, as they have the same name but different types an error would occur, so either change the classname or add a dedicated name to the `@(Rest)Controller` annotation.